# Why the need for usage of "do! Async" style functions within F# Async Workflows?

Tags: .net, asynchronous, f#

I am new to F# Async workflows. Generally code and examples introducing this topic contain examples like the following (simplified):

```
let sleepWorkflow = 
    async{
        printfn "Starting sleep workflow at %O" DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay
        do! Async.Sleep 2000
        printfn "Finished sleep workflow at %O" DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay
    }

Async.RunSynchronously sleepWorkflow
```

I am trying to understand the need for `do! Async.Sleep 2000` as opposed to `do Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)` in its place.

From my understanding, BOTH approaches will run the code **synchronously** at that point.

What is the difference (I assume there must be) and when should one be using one approach versus the other?

Comment: Those two approaches are different. `do!` and `let!` will wait asynchronously, similar to `await` in C#. `Thread.Sleep` is indeed synchronously blocking.

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek what do you mean by "wait asynchronously"? In the do! version the 2nd printfn waits 2 seconds before printing.

Comment: Same way that `await Task.Delay(2000)` is different than `Thread.Sleep(2000)` in C#. [There's a section on MSDN that explains it better than I could](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233250.aspx#Anchor_2) - technically it's about `let!` binding, but `do!` binding behaves the same.

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek confession time - I'm not really a C# coder.

Comment: No worries, there's F#-specific explanation in the link, I think it should address your main question. Main difference: `Thread.Sleep` blocks execution, whereas `do! Async.Sleep` allows for the computation to start, then suspend until the result is available and resume again.

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek Sounds like quite a subtle difference - let me see if I've got it. `Thread.Sleep` holds onto the Async thread - keeps it alive but blocking. `do! Async.Sleep` allows the Async thread to go back into the pool (suspend); creates another nested async thread to do the work on and when this nested thread is finished its work, it gets another thread from the pool to resume the Async computation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92502/discussion-between-sam-and-patryk-cwiek).

Comment: That's pretty much it, Tomas explained it in more detail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference is that using `Thread.Sleep` blocks the current thread so that it cannot do anything else while `Async.Sleep` creates a system timer, releases the current thread (so that it can do other things) and then (after the time elapses) acquires a thread again and runs the rest of the code.

This matters if you have a large number of `async` workflows that run in parallel (because having a dedicated thread for each would be expensive) or when you are running code on the GUI thread (there is just one thread and you should not block it).

To better understand this, you can change the number of thread pool threads to 1 and try the following code using both synchronous and asynchronous blocking:

```
System.Threading.ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(1, 1)
System.Threading.ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(1, 1)

for i in 1 .. 5 do
  async { System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
          printfn "Done" } |> Async.Start

for i in 1 .. 5 do
  async { do! Async.Sleep(1000)
          printfn "Done" } |> Async.Start
```

After running the first `for` loop, you'll the "Done" messages will be printed with 1 second delays (because the one thread is repeatedly blocked for 1 second).

After running the second `for` loop, you'll see "Done" messages printed all at once after 1 second. This is because the asynchronous waiting is not actually blocking the thread and so the 5 timers will all elapse and then use the 1 available thread to do the printing (which takes almost no time).

Comment: Thanks. Would the same reasoning hold for `do! AsyncReadXXX` versus `do ReadXXX` for streams of different kinds? In both (as I understand) you are going to be blocking at this step - just in different ways. I was really just using the "sleep" methods as an example but perhaps they've distracted from my real question.

Comment: Exactly :-). The asynchronous methods on streams use underlying OS primitives to do the reading without blocking a thread (for example, when reading from the network) and so, again, async version of the operation does not block the thread and scales better.

Comment: Are you saying that the IO AsyncReadXXX methods are effectively **not** using CPU resources themselves and are using other hardware to achieve the bulk of their job (disk, network)? Otherwise they would have their own thread 'looking after them'...

Comment: Yes, that's correct. They still use _some_ CPU (to initiate the request and to complete it once they get called with the response from the OS), but they are *not* using CPU to synchronously wait until the operation is done. This depends on what the OS can do, but it certainly includes disk and network IO.

Comment: @Sam Async is good to use together with IO-bound operations (ie operations which performance is limited by IO-operations such as reading from network). "Naive" IO programming leads to threads blocking on IO requests which from CPU perspective takes "ages". Async let's the thread do other stuff while waiting for IO. Since it's IO-bound more cores doesn't help (much). For CPU-bound operations more cores _could_ help, then Parallel operations is what you are looking for.